# How to create a new column in spark Dataset<Row> with a custom type

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have an input Dataset that are records coming from kafka-connect that I convert to a strongly typed Dataset and then perform some transformations.  This has been done because there is a complex structure that must be created as part of the transformation.

The current approach chains a number of Map operations, but details in the source Dataset are lost:

```
Dataset<Row> inputDs = spark.readStream().format("kafka").load();

Dataset<MyClass> transformDf = inputDs
            .map(new JsonDeserializationMapper(MyClass.class), Encoders.bean(MyClass.class))
            .map(new TransformMapper(), Encoders.bean(MyClass.class))
            .map(new DataAugmentationMapper(), Encoders.bean(MyClass.class));
```

Is there a way to create a strongly typed column in a dataset instead of creating a new Dataset and lose all other data from the source Dataset?  Something like a Dataset with a schema of:

```
----------------------------------------
key:String | value:String | obj:MyClass
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: what do you mean by "details in the source Dataset are lost"?

Comment: In our case, the Kafka connect data (initial rows) contains the source topic, key, value, etc.  When transformed into a strongly typed entity (e.g. MyClass), none of that data is in the Dataset.  If there is no natural key you cannot join the resulting Dataset<MyClass> to the source Dataset<Row>.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem, but I can say that when you convert a DataFrame (Dataset<Row>) to a Dataset you are "saying" to Spark to map only filed in the Type specified. If you doen't want to lose any column/value from source dataFrame  you need to included all the fields in your MyClass and make sure that all transformations applied populate all of them.

Comment: Can you `inputDs.printSchema`? You should see key, value, source topic and some extra metadata.